# How to effectively code MATCH INDEX in r (equivalent to excel)?

Tags: r, excel, indexing, match, lookup-tables

I have two different excel spreadsheets (input and output files). Instead of using the match index functions directly in excel, I would like to use a r script to look up for the values in my matrix in the input file and store the values in the correct cell in my output file.

My input file consists of a matrix (columns and rows) and my output file, too. However, the matrix in the output file is "transposed" and the names of the columns and rows may be arranged in a different order. Hence, I need to use a two-dimensional lookup to find the values in the input file and store them in my output file.

Suppose this this my input file (fictitious numbers for illustration):
[image]

Suppose this is my output file:
[image]

How can I implement the lookup in r such that the  values from my input file are correctly entered in the corresponding cells in the output file using r script? I've stored both my excel files as dataframes.

Your help is highly valuable. Thank you!

```
#clearing workspace
rm(list=ls())

# Load required libraries
library(openxlsx)

# get username 
username <- Sys.getenv("USER")

# Load input and output Excel files
input_file <- paste0("/Users/", username, "/Downloads/input_file.xlsx", collapse = "")
output_file <- paste0("/Users/", username, "/Desktop/output_file.xlsx", collapse = "")

# Load the input and output matrices
input_matrix <- read_xlsx(input_file, sheet = "KLICKHERE")
output_matrix <- read_xlsx(output_file, sheet = "ENTERHERE")
class(input_matrix)

# Transpose the dataframe
transposed_input_matrix <- t(input_matrix)

# Convert the column names to Date objects
colnames(output_matrix) <- as.Date(colnames(output_matrix), format = "%YYYY/%mm/%dd")

# Function to perform the two-dimensional lookup
lookup_and_update <- function(transposed_input_matrix, output_matrix) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(output_matrix)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(output_matrix)) {
      # Get the row and column names in the output matrix
      row_name <- rownames(output_matrix)[i]
      col_name <- colnames(output_matrix)[j]
      
      # Find the corresponding value in the input matrix
      value <- transposed_input_matrix[row_name, col_name]
      
      # Update the value in the output matrix
      output_matrix[i, j] <- value
    }
  }
  return(output_matrix)
}

# Call the lookup function
updated_output_matrix <- lookup_and_update(transposed_input_matrix, output_matrix)

# Save the updated output matrix back to the output Excel file
write.xlsx(updated_output_matrix, output_file, sheetName = "ENTERHERE")
```

```
> dput(input_matrix)
structure(list(quarter = structure(c(1640995200, 1648771200, 
1656633600, 1664582400, 1672531200, 1680307200, 1688169600, 1696118400, 
1704067200, 1711929600, 1719792000, 1727740800, 1735689600, 1743465600, 
1751328000, 1759276800, 1767225600, 1775001600, 1782864000, 1790812800, 
1798761600, 1806537600, 1814400000, 1822348800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), portugal = c(3.2, 1.2617029893181, 
2.60440314593473, 0.205747170894448, 2.99742239259666, 0.454981287908458, 
0.812500920203167, 3.53979030628357, 2.203045423758, 0.054471200265702, 
2.92803826928382, 0.718964340034683, 1.60951470750129, 5.07871970749977, 
5.69403126006479, 1.22925310502368, 3.66396581660635, 2.37878419177338, 
2.29467033332622, 5.03595630837856, 2.25374064291613, 1.69444882698869, 
4.16205429572283, 4.50132478373478), Switzerland = c(4, 2.38038947850657, 
5.47668679859636, 5.91361388434538, 4.77394394868853, 0.51390066344242, 
5.01921886848812, 2.50248783131655, 4.01832050488102, 5.41622706832583, 
5.30149956216031, 3.16778787833323, 2.199973116468, 5.01366343788224, 
4.29923192879718, 4.74615956273584, 1.28422990972834, 0.284477581237545, 
2.08538425170424, 0.463401565316672, 5.19591972413863, 1.48139690105528, 
3.72116283773825, 2.88215533537597), UK1 = c(3, 5.86873632407074, 
5.00564172969994, 4.53205722786764, 2.21527468771027, 4.01342647825025, 
5.38033314419433, 3.94260225784184, 3.32679878460482, 4.44258374317064, 
0.912140741259649, 3.31029041858673, 3.54577260155724, 5.47399328355281, 
2.87960737852272, 0.333399757849791, 1.68600300552304, 0.761656675816694, 
5.60117991518305, 2.41681043343095, 1.47930439097793, 1.96253624751877, 
2.04852072952451, 3.00458221738878), UK2 = c(-1, 3.35979319893751, 
3.41085866605616, 0.560088392935827, 5.13880709708747, 4.12321867925324, 
0.678575131657537, 5.05445686032681, 1.91810878862458, 1.3819304062605, 
0.80241487254838, 5.88840619656107, 1.4643177661779, 1.30971606465739, 
5.27065656469845, 2.59430512488464, 2.43626303990699, 2.6781401256743, 
2.92798363758913, 3.82250194049481, 3.53273150832144, 2.88313585242345, 
2.2629948322944, 1.45945340574197)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L))
>
```

```
> dput(output_matrix)
structure(list(c("Portugal", "Switzerland", "UK"), c(NA, NA, 
NA), c(NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA
), c(NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .Names = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_))
>
```

Comment: hi TFT have you imported the excel files as dataframes?

Comment: also, what is it which is transposing your data? Post your code if it's R. It's much to keep things in the same state, than to transpose the data back and forth

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks for your quick feedback. Yes, I've imported both my excel files as dataframes and I've transposed my input file. I've just posted my r code in my initial request. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: great! thanks for doing that! :-) now one more thing you can do that would be great - run `dput(input_matrix)`, and add the results to your question as well

Comment: Just done it! :) Thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: No worries! Thanks for doing that! I'm just taking a look at it now. It sounds based on what you've said like you've created the output file as a template for what you're wanting, and the code is meant to go through and transform the data you have to fit into this new transposed format. Is this correct?

Comment: a couple of questions: 1. what do you want to happen with the two UK values for each date? 2. Is this for a particular use? In general R handles columnwise data much better than rowwise, so depending on what the use case is the input file might be faster

Comment: e.g. it's relatively straightforward to filter a date column to those between x date and y date, but much harder to do it if the column names are dates

Comment: "It sounds based on what you've said like you've created the output file as a template for what you're wanting, and the code is meant to go through and transform the data you have to fit into this new transposed format. Is this correct?" --> correct! /// 1. what do you want to happen with the two UK values for each date? --> I would like to be flexible to define which UK I would like to use. I would also be happy to transpose the output matrix instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255235/discussion-between-mark-and-tft).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1. Turn the quarter into a date (it was a datetime)
2. Make the data long, turning all of the country columns into their own rows, with the country names put into a column called "country"
3. Clean the "country" column - if it includes "UK", make it "UK", otherwise, make it title case
4. Make it wider again, using the quarter dates as column names, and the values as the values. Because we now have multiple values for the UK row, we turn them into strings using an anonymous function. `collapse = ","` means it joins multiple ones with a comma in the middle of the values.
5. Write it out to a csv file

Code:

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse)

input_matrix |>
  mutate(quarter = as.Date(quarter)) |>
  pivot_longer(-quarter, names_to = "country", values_to = "value") |>
  mutate(country = ifelse(str_detect(country, "UK"), "UK", str_to_title(country))) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = "quarter", values_from = "value", values_fn = ~paste0(.x, collapse = ",")) |>
  write_csv("output.csv")
```

Output:

```
country,2022-01-01,2022-04-01,2022-07-01,2022-10-01,2023-01-01,2023-04-01,2023-07-01,2023-10-01,2024-01-01,2024-04-01,2024-07-01,2024-10-01,2025-01-01,2025-04-01,2025-07-01,2025-10-01,2026-01-01,2026-04-01,2026-07-01,2026-10-01,2027-01-01,2027-04-01,2027-07-01,2027-10-01
Portugal,3.2,1.2617029893181,2.60440314593473,0.205747170894448,2.99742239259666,0.454981287908458,0.812500920203167,3.53979030628357,2.203045423758,0.054471200265702,2.92803826928382,0.718964340034683,1.60951470750129,5.07871970749977,5.69403126006479,1.22925310502368,3.66396581660635,2.37878419177338,2.29467033332622,5.03595630837856,2.25374064291613,1.69444882698869,4.16205429572283,4.50132478373478
Switzerland,4,2.38038947850657,5.47668679859636,5.91361388434538,4.77394394868853,0.51390066344242,5.01921886848812,2.50248783131655,4.01832050488102,5.41622706832583,5.30149956216031,3.16778787833323,2.199973116468,5.01366343788224,4.29923192879718,4.74615956273584,1.28422990972834,0.284477581237545,2.08538425170424,0.463401565316672,5.19591972413863,1.48139690105528,3.72116283773825,2.88215533537597
UK,"3,-1","5.86873632407074,3.35979319893751","5.00564172969994,3.41085866605616","4.53205722786764,0.560088392935827","2.21527468771027,5.13880709708747","4.01342647825025,4.12321867925324","5.38033314419433,0.678575131657537","3.94260225784184,5.05445686032681","3.32679878460482,1.91810878862458","4.44258374317064,1.3819304062605","0.912140741259649,0.80241487254838","3.31029041858673,5.88840619656107","3.54577260155724,1.4643177661779","5.47399328355281,1.30971606465739","2.87960737852272,5.27065656469845","0.333399757849791,2.59430512488464","1.68600300552304,2.43626303990699","0.761656675816694,2.6781401256743","5.60117991518305,2.92798363758913","2.41681043343095,3.82250194049481","1.47930439097793,3.53273150832144","1.96253624751877,2.88313585242345","2.04852072952451,2.2629948322944","3.00458221738878,1.45945340574197"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just transpose your input_matrix into an output_matrix?

like:

```
output_df <- data.frame(t(input_matrix))[-1, ]
```

with some adjustions:

```
colnames(output_df) <- input_matrix$quarter
output_df$time <- names(input_matrix)[-1]
output_df <- output_df[, c(ncol(output_df), 1:(ncol(output_df) - 1))]
```

PS: Any instructions on how to combine UK1 and UK2?

Comment: hi Near Lin! check my chat with OP ! :-)